# Ubuntu server hardware migration

Tags: server

I am trying to move my server SSD to a new computer and all I get is a blinking cursor.

I have tried holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>, and I tried <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but nothing happens.

Comment: You've provided few specifics, what Ubuntu Server system (Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Release?), what architecture & are they the same? and what release of the Ubuntu Server product. Ubuntu Server products usually use the GA kernel stack (ie. oldest & most stable), which can be a problem with newer hardware, so have you installed both stacks? (*whilst on older system? its something I tend to do when going to newer hardware*) or tried selecting different kernels at grub?  tried selecting runlevel 1? etc

Comment: Have you tried running boot repair?